# confused on to write test case for the below code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

i am confused on how to write a test case for the below code

```
import React, { Ref, RefForwardingComponent } from "react";

export default function forward<P extends { forwardRef?: Ref<any> }>(
  BaseComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentType<Omit<P, "forwardRef"> & { ref?: P["forwardRef"] }> {

  const forwardRef: RefForwardingComponent<any, P> = (props, ref) => (
    <BaseComponent {...props} forwardRef={ref} />
  );

  return React.forwardRef<any, P>(forwardRef) as any;

}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how this is used?

Comment: it is to pass arguments into a dom element with dynamic content @NickMcCurdy